# WSL does not have a switch?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-for-windows

As a novice I am beginning to experiment with containers. On my desktop I have wsl2 ubuntu and docker-desktop installed. Wsl does not have a virtual switch active to configure on my network connections. My question is how do I initialize a switch via PowerShell for Wsl that can be accessed through the windows/-network--connections UI? And out of curiosity, could I remote into docker containers onboard the windows os from WSL instead of installing docker.io in the virtual WSL instance?